# Java "invalid AssignmentOperator" error on eclipse and the other errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java and i'm trying to do a calculator but when i write "+" or "-" it says "invalid AssignmentOperator" and it gives a lot error without this. The code is below.

And sorry for my english.

(sayi means number, sonuc means result, toplama/çıkarma/bölme/çarpma means add subtract/multiply/divide, last writing is (after the last println) is an error message.

Please help me, is my code wrong?

```
package calismayanhesapmakinesi;

#import java.util.Scanner;

public class calismayanhesapmakinesi {
 public static void main(String[] args){
 int sayi1,sayi2,sonuc;
 char islem;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 sayi1 = input.nextInt();
 System.out.println("1.Sayıyı giriniz");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 sayi2 = input.nextInt();
 System.out.println("2.sayıyı giriniz");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 islem = input.nextchar;
 System.out.println("Yapmak istediğiniz işlem?");
 System.out.println("(Toplama için:T, Çıkarma için: C, Çarpma için:A, Bölme için:B yazınız.)");
 if(islem=T){
  sayi1 + sayi2 = sonuc;
  system.out.println("Sonuç:"+sonuc);
 }
 else if(islem=C){
  sayi1-sayi2 = sonuc;
  System.out.println("Sonuç:"+sonuc);
 }
 else if(islem=A){
  sayi1 * sayi2 = sonuc;
  system.out.println("Sonuç:"+sonuc);
 }
 else if(islem=B){
  sayi1/sayi2 = sonuc;
  system.out.println("Sonuç:"+sonuc);
 }
 else{
  system.out.println("Lütfen T, C, A ve B harflerinden birini yazınız.");
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ostensibly, you need to use `islem == C` rather than `islem = C` as the former is a test for equality, the latter is assignment.

Then, you need to quote the character literal: use `islem == 'C'` etc.

Lastly, You need to write the *assignment* the other way round: `sonuc = sayi1 + sayi2;`

Answer (score 0):

Your mathematical expressions should be of the form:

```
sonuc = sayi1 + sayi2;
```

and not:

```
sayi1 + sayi2 = sonuc;
```

The variable that you're assigning the value to, goes on the left-hand side. Also, the equality comparisons you make in your `if` statement should use `==` and not `=`.

You also haven't defined `C`, `T`, `B`, or `A`.

I suggest reading up on some Java basics and understanding what the syntax errors mean.

Comment: When i'm trying to add this lane:"#import java.util.Scanner" it says "- The import System cannot be resolved
 - Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete 
  this token"

Comment: What's the problem hear?

Comment: Drop the `#` from `import`. Java is not C or C++!

Comment: Now i have defined the A,B,C and T but on the scanner lanes it says ""Multiple markers at this line
 - Duplicate local variable input
 - Scanner cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - Scanner cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: @Yasir I strongly suggest reading up on basic Java syntax and the Java API. It looks like you're missing some fundamental concepts about the Java language. The errors you are running into are trivial. Try googling for them and I'm sure you'll find solutions.

Comment: I solve all of the problems myself and now, its working thank you.

Comment: @Yasir Glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Thanks and i also change it to work with decimal (i dont know is it true so i'll give an example: Like 1.86) and also result can be decimal too. And i also add a squareroot function. Whatever, thank all of you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable being assigned a value goes on the left.

sounuc = sayi1 + sayi2

The error is because it is expecting the assignment operator =, but it is finding a math operator